# sci-kit learns TransformerMixin has strange fit_transform behavior

Tags: python, scikit-learn

The `fit_transform` method inherited from `TransformerMixin`, doesn't pass the `y` variable to the `transform` method.
 Here is a minimal example

```
class UslessPrint(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        print(y)
        return self
    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        print(y)
        return X

usless = mc.UslessPrint()
usless.fit_transform([[1, 2], [2, 1]], [0, 1])
```

the output is:

```
[0, 1]
None
```

instead of the expected

```
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
```

is such behavior normal, or is this a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an intended behavior of `TransformerMixin`, not a bug.

`sklearn.Base.TransformerMixin`'s `fit_transform` doesn't utilize `y` in its `transform`.

From [the latest version of sklearn from github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7b136e9/sklearn/base.py#L437):

```
class TransformerMixin(object):
    """Mixin class for all transformers in scikit-learn."""

    def fit_transform(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        """Fit to data, then transform it.
        Fits transformer to X and y with optional parameters fit_params
        and returns a transformed version of X.
        Parameters
        ----------
        X : numpy array of shape [n_samples, n_features]
            Training set.
        y : numpy array of shape [n_samples]
            Target values.
        Returns
        -------
        X_new : numpy array of shape [n_samples, n_features_new]
            Transformed array.
        """
        # non-optimized default implementation; override when a better
        # method is possible for a given clustering algorithm
        if y is None:
            # fit method of arity 1 (unsupervised transformation)
            return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
        else:
            # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)
            return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
```

As you can see, `TransformerMixin` passes `X` only to `transform`, leaving `y` as `None` in your code.